What is this symbol? Looks like a resistor with a solid line below and joining the 2 ends
First timer at attempting board level repair...
I am attempting to fix a motherboard that got damaged by a failed hard drive. There was a dead short between GND and 5v.
I found a burn component that looks like it could have been a resistor.
On schematics for this board, I found this symbol  (circled in red):
What is the symbol?  Maybe a 0 ohm resistor?

Its value is "0_0805_5%", which indeed stands for a 0 Ohm resistor in a 0805 package.
If that's what's burnt out, the chip that it's connected to on the "+5VS_HDD" line is dead.

Thank you so much.
Your answer / confirmation is appreciated.
Indeed as you said, the chip (on the HDD) is dead.  Have an identical mainboard for the HDD, will swop and cross my fingers... will test it in a cheap external drive first

Great answer! This is a 0-ohm 0805 resistor with a 5% tolerance. But ±5% of 0 is 0 - it doesn’t mean it’s a perfect 0-ohm resistor. So, labelling it with a 5% tolerance is somewhat misleading for a 0-ohm resistor!

@15Volts I know at least for YAGEO resistors, the datasheet says that the letter code for 5% tolerance is used when ordering zero ohm jumpers. I don’t know how universal that is across brands though. shrug
